# Windows command-line command to list hidden folders

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a command on the Windows command-line that can list hidden folders?

I've tried `dir -a:dh` but that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the following command:

```
dir /a:hd C:\folder\
```

The difference between what you were typing and this command is that you were using a `-` to indicate the switch, not a `/`. In most windows command line applications, this doesn't matter, but in the case of the `dir` command, you *must* use a slash, not a dash.

The `/a` switch changes which attributes are displayed. `h` shows hidden files and `d` shows just directories. Make sure you keep the trailing slash on the end of the folder path. I just tested, and it worked fine.

Comment: What's the point of the `:` character in `/a:hd`? Omitting it and simply doing `dir /ah` seems to work well....

Comment: How can I make `dir` display all files folders and the attributes of each item?

Comment: see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755121(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: I get "dir : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '/a' does not exist." when I run "dir /a:hd"

Comment: It looks like Royi and Pacerier might be in Powershell prompts? When I open up a `cmd.exe` it works as advertised (and doesn't work in, eg, a VS Code Powershell terminal). [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66859219/1028230). `cmd /r dir /a` is [a neat workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66859219/how-to-list-all-files-in-a-folder-do-cmds-dir-a-in-powershell#comment118185816_66859219).

Answer (score 17):

- `dir/a` should show hidden folders.
- `dir /a:d` shows all directories.
- `dir /a:h` shows all hidden files.

Try `dir /adh` (without the colon) to combine.

Comment: And "dir /ad-h" shows only non-hidden directories, like "dir".

Comment: Why the down vote? The answer is correct.

Comment: Btw if we only do `dir /ad` (as opposed to `dir /ad-h` and `dir /adh`), what's the default `h` behavior?

Answer (score 7):

To list all files and folders, *including* hidden and system ones, use `dir` with `/a` flag:

```
dir /a C:\
```

Comment: _If you use the parameter `/a` without specifying any attributes, the command `dir` displays the names of all files, including hidden and system files._ from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir