# Can I run something that makes sure all of my folder Attributes are at the default settings?

Tags: command-line

I did something I didn't want to, based on this page . . . [Windows command-line command to list hidden folders](https://superuser.com/questions/277379/windows-command-line-command-to-list-hidden-folders)

I was trying to figure out if there were any errors in what my bat file was doing.

To get the output, I thought I should go to the "Startup" folder in cmd.exe, which is hidden, and run:  Startup.bat > testlog.txt 2> testerrors.txt

To get there, I would have to un-hide some folders.

I found the above page, and ran the attrib command with those switches.

I think I did this in the C:\ProgramData folder (normally hidden)

I think that I put this in an elevated command prompt, based on the second answer . . . attrib -s -h -r /s /d *.* and hit Enter.

Maybe I just put this in . . . attrib -s -h -r /s /d

I thought, I'll just go fast and not think, nothing can happen . . . then, of course, I read on that same page, also, that this can alter your folder attributes . . . they should preface that with the word "CAUTION."

I think I did see a lot of "NOT ACCESSIBLE . . . " flashing by . . . it was doing something.

Is there any way to tell if I altered my folder attributes or not?

---

Does this fix I have at the bottom fix it, or not?

Quick way to reset all security permissions to default? (Windows 7)

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d09a393b-68df-43de-9f31-735f83242497/quick-way-to-reset-all-security-permissions-to-default-windows-7?forum=w7itprosecurity&ppud=4

"Just run in a elevated prompt the following command."

secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose

This did something, but, how can I tell if it did what I want, and things are back to normal?  I don't know if secedit applies to folder attributes or not.

Is there a folder Attribute auditing program?

Comment: AFAIK, the answers are no, no, none, you can't and no. But I'm interested in answers by users more deeply in the topic than me.

Comment: You don't need an attribute auditing program. run `dir /a:X /s "PATH"` where `X` is the desired attribute to check (`h`:hidden, `s`:system, `r`:read-only) and `"PATH"` is the folder address. This will list all the files with desired attribute. BTW, no one died of changing attributes, it's not as dangerous as NTFS permissions.

Comment: I guess I phrased that wrong.  Not an auditing program . . . but, a program that puts them back at the default values . . . Is that the function of the secedit command?

Comment: I make a couple of clones with Clonezilla once per month . . . I determined that the fix, in this case, was to just replace the C: drive with one of those. It was only about 20 days old, and I had made no significant software changes.  I keep all my data files on a separate, secondary D: drive.